# Angularjs cross-domain OPTIONS request innitial connection slow

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, request, cross-domain

I'm having issues with OPTIONS requests, sometimes (random) requests take more than 2-3 secs. This waiting period is named on chrome console as "Innitial connection" and on Firefox firebug as "Bloqued".
After this waiting period the request takes about 60 ms.
When all goes well the OPTIONS request allways takes 60 ms aprox.
We are using angularJS 1.4.7 and the $http service to make the api calls.

What could be the issue? Thnx

[issue example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFHv9.png)

Comment: Probably just the webserver on the CORS system being slow?

Comment: CORS is handled by NGINX is setting the headers for cross-domain on all requests and returning a 204 response when OPTIONS method